# Python | Is at at all possible to replace this function with a lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

This is the code:

```
def print_limit(lim):
  counter = 2
  prev_val= 1+counter 
  print(1)
  while counter+prev_val < lim:
    print(counter+1)
    counter +=1

limit = int(input('Limit: '))
print_limit(limit)
```

Is it actually possible? I am new to lambda expressions, can you do this sort of thing with them? Thanks James:)

Comment: What would be the purpose of such a thing?

Comment: This is literally what you're doing (Python 3): `[print(x) for x in (y for y in range(1,lim-2) if y != 2)]`.

Comment: Yes, probably some hacky way, but you *shouldn't*

Comment: What function? Your code doesn't define any.

Comment: I've rolled this back to the initial question. None of the given answers make any sense with your new question, even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47824545/4799172) quite generic answer (`print_limit` doesn't exist in your code).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP (A) is requesting to do something nonsensical without attempting to understand the constructs involved, and (B) has modified the question to be internally inconsistent after valid answers were posted.

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically, yes:

```
print_limit = lambda lim: (print(1), [print(c + 1) for c in range(2, lim- 3)])
```

But the real question is why? That code I gave does the same thing as yours, but it looks hideous. It's a bunch of mangled gibberish that actually happens to do something (though I really don't understand what).

Lambdas aren't a full replacement for functions. They are meant for when you need to pass a function to something, but the function is very simple, usually something like:

```
def myfunc(args):
    return expression
```

It's a fairly common pattern with things like sorting:

```
mylist = [(0, 2), (4, 3), (5, 1)]
mylist.sort(key=lambda v: v[1])
mylist
# [(5, 1), (0, 2), (4, 3)]
```

In fact, they feel so strongly about not using lambdas too broadly that the official style guide for Python, PEP 8, says you shouldn't even give a name to one.

If you intend to reuse it, give it a real function definition.

Comment: Always fun when the OP edits their question to be entirely different to what they posted....

Comment: There's also the fact that you have a tuple with None followed by a list of Nones as your return value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can put while-loops inside lambdas, and if you could, you shouldn't. You can get around this with `map` or similar, but be aware of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Lambda expressions are usually short and easy to read. Your `print_limit` function is more readable as it is.

Comment: Normally I don't like this sort of answer, but I feel like you've captured the essence of the problem so well that +1.

Comment: Thanks for +1 and feedback. I'm not very experienced here, and would like to avoid "this sort of answer" in the future, but I'm not sure if I unambiguously understand what you referred to. Is it because it's opinionated?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, I don't like "you could but shouldn't" without a both a detailed explanation of how you could and why you shouldn't. I think this answer is pretty good though because what OP wants to do is completely nonsensical, to a point that it's worthless to show an implementation. That's just my opinion though and you shouldn't take it as anything more than that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with the function is printing `1,3,4,... lim-3`
that's easily achieved by a range function

```
list_limit = lambda lim: [1] + list(range(lim - 2))
print_list = lambda lim: [print(x) for x in list_limit(lim)]
```

Why you'd want such a function is still unclear to me.

or simply

```
print_limit = lambda lim: [print(x) for x in range(1, lim - 2) if x!=2]
```

Comment: you mean `list(range(3, lim - 2))`, I think, in your first solution

Comment: yes. my bad. Thank you @AkshatMahajan.

Comment: @srj They are triangular numbers, and it is meant to output 1,3, 6,10,15 e.c.t not 1,3,5,6, ......